# how to set headers in jquery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a web service with rest, but it requires two headers `Finicity-App-Key` and `Content-Type`. In the site's example for 
Partner Authentication, they use `curl` and it sends it with the two headers. But when I try to set it in jquery, if I check the network tab in dev tools, I don't see those two headers on the ajax I made. They seem to show under `access-control-request-headers` like `content-type,finicity-app-key`.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

https://developer.finicity.com/admin/docs

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://api.finicity.com/aggregation/v2/partners/authentication",
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "application/xml",
                data : '<credentials><partnerId>24455d81430647</partnerId><partnerSecret>v09TAUzbYgsfKnbTFOGn0</partnerSecret></credentials>',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Finicity-App-Key', 'a0874b0eda76ae7918c779f8eeef92c1a');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
                },
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function(xhr,status,error){
                    alert("Error:" + JSON.stringify(xhr));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your url',
    headers: { 'Finicity-App-Key': 'a0874b0eda76ae7918c779f8eeef92c1a' }
});
```

Comment: I got it working, it just needs to be run from server with node.js.

Comment: @omega did you have to do it with node because of CORS? what was the error you were getting back?